# Add Values to the Grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I’m working on upgrading our application vaadin version from 7.7.24 to 8.13.3. We’ve completed all the dependency issues and I’m able to start the application locally.
I'm facing some issues with adding data in the Grid and I'm not able to find alternatives for getContainerDataSource and addRow in vaadin 8.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
public void runSchedulesOnce(){
    for(Object r : schedulesGrid.getSelectedItems())
    {
        String name = schedulesGrid.getContainerDataSource().getItem(r).getItemProperty(COLUMN_SCHEDULE_NAME).getValue().toString();
        controller.runSchedule(name);
    }
}

private void initSchedulesGrid()
{
    schedulesGrid = new Grid();

    schedulesGrid.setSizeFull();
    schedulesGrid.setColumnReorderingAllowed(false);
    schedulesGrid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    schedulesGrid.getEditor().setEnabled(false);

    schedulesGrid.addColumn(Schedule::getSchedule_name).setCaption("Schedule Name");
    schedulesGrid.addColumn(Schedule::getDelivery_method).setCaption("Delivery Method");
    schedulesGrid.addColumn(Schedule::getName).setCaption("Name");
    schedulesGrid.addColumn(Schedule::getCron).setCaption("Cron");

    // Disallow resizing to prevent scroll
    for (Grid.Column column : schedulesGrid.getColumns())
    {
        column.setResizable(false);
    }

    schedulesGrid.getEditor().setEnabled(false);
    schedulesGrid.addItemClickListener(newGridDetailsListener(schedulesGrid));

    schedulesGrid.setSizeFull();
    schedulesGrid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.MULTI);

    List<List<String>> schedules = controller.getSchedules();
    for (List<String> l : schedules)
    {
        schedulesGrid.addRow(l.get(0), l.get(1), l.get(2), l.get(3));
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is preventing you to use `schedulesGrid.addRow(...);`?
Just make the `schedulesGrid` a variable visible in the `runSchedulesOnce`method

Comment: The Container API was replaced with the DataProvider API in Vaadin 8. https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-providers might get you forward. Adding a row, for example, would happen through the DataProvider, not the Grid.